# Help with multirow

Tags: multirow

I'm trying to get my table correctly displayed but I don't know why it's not working:
[image]

Can someone please help me? Here is the code of the picture:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[bottom=25mm,top=25mm, left=30mm, right=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla, es-noshorthands, es-nosectiondot]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ph]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{Blah} \\
    \hline
\multirow{1}{*}{C1F1} &  C2F1 & C3F1 & C4F1\\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{C1F2} & C2F2 \\& C2F2 &\multirow{2}{*}{C3F2} & \multirow{2}{*}{C4F2}\\ \hline
\multirow{1}{*}{C1F3} & C2F3 & C3F3 & C4F3 \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{C1F4} & C2F4 \\& C2F4 &\multirow{2}{*}{C3F4}  & \multirow{2}{*}{C4F4}\\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{blablabla}
  \label{blabla}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to use `\multirow{-2}{*}{C3F2}` (note the minus sign), which means the two rows above _this_ row.

Comment: ...or move the `\multirow` command up one cell.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but if I do that the vertical line between columns is broken in the middle of the cell :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should fix your problem. I moved the \multirow one line up and created the empty cells in which the multirow expands. Also I removed the \multirow{1} and organized the table a bit.

```
C1F1                  & C2F1 & C3F1                  & C4F1                  \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{C1F2} & C2F2 & \multirow{2}{*}{C3F2} & \multirow{2}{*}{C4F2} \\
                      & C2F2 &                       &                       \\ \hline
C1F3                  & C2F3 & C3F3                  & C4F3                  \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{C1F4} & C2F4 & \multirow{2}{*}{C3F4} & \multirow{2}{*}{C4F4} \\
                      & C2F4 &                       &                       \\ \hline
```

[image]